# IIS Redirection - command line

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7, command-line

I have a website say www.mywebsite.com/demo . When ever if anyone requests this site, i want to navigate to another website www.myanotherwebsite.com . I know that this can be done in IIS by using the HTTP Redirect feature. But since i want to do this for different websites, I would like to write a bat file which would run the command to set the redirect url for a website. Can anyone please help me how to set the redirection URL through command line?

Edit: I'm using IIS 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this PowerShell script

http://forums.iis.net/t/1162778.aspx

```
Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/httpRedirect "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Value @{enabled="true";destination="domain.com";exactDestination="true";httpResponseStatus="Permanent"}
```